# How to display an Alert in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.alertbox').click(function(){
    alert('You Clicked on Click Here Button');
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
  
<div>
  <a class="alertbox" href="#clicked"> Click Here</a>
</div>
```

I want the alert to be displayed in the bootstrap Modal.

Comment: You cannot contain the JS alert box . If you want something like alert box in a modal,design it using CSS/HTML and trigger it using JS/jQuery

Comment: Some info about creating a modal with bootstrap http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Are you trying to display a modal with "alert" text inside? Or are you trying to trigger a browser alert from a link within a modal?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create the error div in modal body. and set error

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#alertbox').click(function(){
    $("#error").html("You Clicked on Click here Button");
      $('#myModal').modal("show");
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="alertbox">Click here</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="error"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably I didn't understood your question correctly, but you can't use the alert function to display a message insidea a page element. Alert displays a system alert outside the page dom.

If you want to display a message inside a modal you have to include (or inject) the modal markup in your page html, then you simply show/hide the modal via bootstrap functions.

You have a very good example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)