# OnEventClicked function issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap 4` Beta and `JavaScript` for my university project, I'm making some calendar event function. I want to know how to use Bootstrap's Popup modal?

Here's my code:

```
dp.onEventClicked = function(args) {
  alert("clicked:Test " + args.e.id("A"));

};
```

Comment: can you post more detailed source code?

Comment: I think the question have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803865/how-to-display-an-alert-in-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: @Srax Thanks sir, I can  fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link [bootstrap library](http://bootboxjs.com/) that implement alert
assign bootbox.alert function to window.alert

```
 window.alert=bootbox.alert
```

Comment: yes you can use they have done very good implementation of alert,confirm,prompt and others