# Dialog box not appearing Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to submit a form and alert the user once the form has been submitted. I am using the bootstrap theme Cosmo from Bootswatch. When I submit the form, the scream dims as if the dialog is appearing but the dialog never appears. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="content">
        <div id="infoContactMe" class="info">
            <form action="contactMe.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Contact Me</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactEmail1" name="contactEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" id="contactName" name="contactName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleSelect1">Catagory</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="contactCatagory" name="contactCatagory">
                        <option id="defulat">--Select Catagory--</option>
                        <option id="1">General Enquiry</option>
                        <option id="2">View Private Project</option>
                        <option id="3">Reference Contact</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleTextarea">Query</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="contactQuery" name="contactQuery" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="contact">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>

                <!--Dialog Box-->
                <div class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="contactDiaglog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p id="confirmation">Modal body text goes here.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I have a basic JQuery script I have written to display the dialog. This will also eventually submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact').click(function(){
  $("#confirmation").html("You Clicked on Click here Button");
    $('#contactDiaglog').modal("show");
  });
});
```

I found the code to do this by following the anwser posted here:

> [How to display an Alert in Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803865/how-to-display-an-alert-in-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `id="contactDiaglog"` with `<div class="modal">` in modal html like below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact').click(function(){
  $("#confirmation").html("You Clicked on Click here Button");
    $('#contactDiaglog').modal("show");
  });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
        <div id="infoContactMe" class="info">
            <form action="contactMe.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Contact Me</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactEmail1" name="contactEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" id="contactName" name="contactName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleSelect1">Catagory</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="contactCatagory" name="contactCatagory">
                        <option id="defulat">--Select Catagory--</option>
                        <option id="1">General Enquiry</option>
                        <option id="2">View Private Project</option>
                        <option id="3">Reference Contact</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleTextarea">Query</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="contactQuery" name="contactQuery" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="contact">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>

                <!--Dialog Box-->
                <div class="modal" id="contactDiaglog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p id="confirmation">Modal body text goes here.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <div class="content">
            <div id="infoContactMe" class="info">
                <form action="contactMe.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Contact Me</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactEmail1" name="contactEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" id="contactName" name="contactName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleSelect1">Catagory</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="contactCatagory" name="contactCatagory">
                            <option id="defulat">--Select Catagory--</option>
                            <option id="1">General Enquiry</option>
                            <option id="2">View Private Project</option>
                            <option id="3">Reference Contact</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleTextarea">Query</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="contactQuery" name="contactQuery" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="contact">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>

                    <!--Dialog Box-->
                    <div class="modal" id="contactDiaglog" >
                            <div class="modal-dialog" id="contactDiaglog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p id="confirmation">Modal body text goes here.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact').click(function(){
  $("#confirmation").html("You Clicked on Click here Button");
    $('#contactDiaglog').modal("show");
  });
});
```